# Can't use any Atom Python IDE functions

Tags: python, atom-editor

I am trying to setup Atom as a Python IDE.

I have installed `atom-ide-ui`, and `ide-python` packages. Python and pyls are installed as well to the latest versions. Nonetheless I am not able to use any of the functions the packages should provide (e.g. autocomplete, highlighting, etc.), they just do not seem to be active.

I have tried to set the `python-ide` Python Executable path to the actual install path (`C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python`), as I though it could be a problem with the defaults. Still nothing.

I am wondering if I am missing any import step in the setup, or if I am using something wrongly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Did you load the language-python extension? Its necessary to run Python. Was your file in color after opening a valid python code?

You should also load the extension named Script. Script is required to run your python file. after you start atom, under the Packages menu you'll see the word Script. Click on this and you'll get another pane that says run script. Click on this to run you python code/

Comment: Hi, language-python is installed as well as the script package. The code comes up syntax highlighted in the editor, and I am able to run it successfully. The issue is that I am not ale to activate any of the functions related to ide-python like linting, or predictions